# colorbox: Sending user to another page

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I have my colorbox data:

```
 <a href="#div1">How do I select my gift?</a>
      <div style="display:none">
          <div class="" id="div1">
              here is some text w/ a <a href="to new page">foo</a>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('.div1').colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
 </script>
```

When the user clicks on "foo", I want the user to be directed to the page "to new page"  Right now colorbox seems to just collapse.  What's the correct way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best answer, here is what I did and it works:

```
<a href="to new page" class="external">foo</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.external').click() { 
    location.href=this.getAttribute('href'); 
    return false;
 })
```